# My Flask-Admin ModelView's __init__ has no application context—when does it normally get one?

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-admin

I have a working sample Flask-Admin application [on GitHub](https://github.com/ernstki/flask-admin-column-labels) which queries a view (itself based on MySQL's `information_schema.TABLES`) in order to dynamically update a ModelView's `column_labels` and `column_descriptions` properties. There's also a small template modification to add tooltips to the header row containing the column comments from the database.

I put a lot of effort into figuring this out because it seemed foolish to re-type column descriptions in my Python code when they had *already* been entered into the database using the `COMMENT` SQL keyword during table creation.

In the simple test app, everything works as expected; I receive the `model` and `session` parameters given to the `ModelView`'s `__init__` method, and I use the `session` to query the other model for the column labels / comments, update `self.column_labels` and `self.column_descriptions` on the view, then call `super()`.

[image: Animated GIF showing column tooltips]

However, in a more complicated app, I get the dreaded `RuntimeError: No application found. Either work inside a view function or push an application context` when I try to query the other model within a `ModelView`'s `__init__` method. The only marked difference I would note between the demo app and my "real" app is that I import a `SQLAlchemy` object instantiated in another `.py` file and then invoke its `init_app()` in my `app.py` to wire it up to the Flask instance.

**Edit: which is *exactly* what the problem is**; `SQLAlchemy` instances created using in the usual way, demonstrated in the [Flask-SQLAlchemy Quickstart](https://flask-sqlalchemy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/quickstart/#a-minimal-application) get a proper Flask application instance in their `__init__()`s; when I use `db.init_app(app)`, I get the `No application found` error instead.

My question is: **at which point does a Flask-Admin `ModelView` start existing inside a Flask application context?** Why are circumstances different for `import db from somewhere.py; db.init_app(app)` vs. `db = SQLAlchemy(app)`? Is there any way that I can trace the start-up process of a Flask application and hook into that exact moment so I can see what's going on here?

Here are the two basic parts that are involved (complete source [for](https://github.com/ernstki/flask-admin-column-labels/blob/master/models.py) [each](https://github.com/ernstki/flask-admin-column-labels/blob/master/views.py) is on GitHub, as noted above):

#### The model that provides the column "metadata," including comments

```
# models.py
# [SQLALchemy imports and declaration of 'Base']
class ColumnProperty(Base):
    # this view is based on MySQL's 'information_schema.TABLES'
    __tablename__ = 'v_column_properties'

    parent_table = Column(String(64), primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String(64), primary_key=True)
    # [some fields elided]
    comment = Column(String(1024)) # type: str
```

and

#### The `ModelView` which queries the above model upon instantiation

```
# views.py
from flask_admin.contrib.sqla import ModelView

class TestView(ModelView): 
    def __init__(self, model, session, **kwargs):
        from models import ColumnProperty as cp

        descriptions = {}
        q = session.query(cp).filter(cp.parent_table==model.__tablename__)

        for row in q.all():
            descriptions[row.name] = row.comment

        self.column_descriptions = descriptions 
        super(TestView, self).__init__(model, session, **kwargs)
```

Comment: As shown in [this branch](https://github.com/ernstki/flask-admin-column-labels/compare/use-init-app-instead) what's _different_ between the simple demo app and my real Flask-Admin application _is the problem_. Which leaves me all the more confused about why anyone would ever use `init_app()` in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

I would override the `render` method of `ModelView` and set your `column_descriptions` there. Obviously you could setup some kind of caching mechanism to reduce the number of database queries.

Something like (completely untested) - note use of `self.session` in querying:

```
# views.py
from flask_admin.contrib.sqla import ModelView

class TestView(ModelView):

    def render(self, template, **kwargs):
        from models import ColumnProperty as cp

        descriptions = {}
        q = self.session.query(cp).filter(cp.parent_table==model.__tablename__)

        for row in q.all():
            descriptions[row.name] = row.comment

        self.column_descriptions = descriptions

        super(TestView, self).render(template, **kwargs)
```

Comment: That was one of the things I considered, but it assumes the request starts at the index view, rather than a user going straight to, say, the "create" form, where those column descriptions would need to be established already, too.

Comment: Initializing `column_labels` and `column_descriptions` in `__init__` _does_ work as you'd expect, as long as you don't use `db.init_app`. I think some hint is in the Flask-SQLAlchemy [API documentation](http://flask-sqlalchemy.pocoo.org/2.3/api/), which mentions that `db = SQLAlchemy(app)` and `db.init_app(app)` differ in that "_in the first case methods like create_all() and drop_all() will work all the time but in the second case a flask.Flask.app_context() has to exist_." I'm hoping to gain a better idea of _why_ before I either answer my own question or close it as "not constructive."

Comment: @TheDudeAbides - the render method is called in index/new/edit view. Maybe that's the place to put your initialization.

Answer (score 0):

I realize I'm a bit late to the show but since I had a similar problem I'll share my findings.

It seems that in order to get an application context for the `ModelView` you have to initialize it within `with app.app_context()`, like this, in case of your `app.py`:

```py
...
#app.py
with app.app_context():
   admin = Admin(app, name="{}-admin".format(cfg['database']),
              index_view=AdminIndexView(name='Admin Home', url='/'),
              template_mode='bootstrap3')

   admin.add_view(TestView(Test, db.session))
   admin.add_view(ColumnPropertiesView(ColumnProperty, db.session))
...
```

In you prefer using an application factory pattern, you could do something along these lines:

```py
#app.py
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask_admin import Admin, AdminIndexView

db = SQLAlchemy()

def create_app():
    """The application factory"""
    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.config.from_object('app.config')

    db.init_app(app)

    with app.app_context():
        admin = Admin(app, name="{}-admin".format(cfg['database']),
                   index_view=AdminIndexView(name='Admin Home', url='/'),
                   template_mode='bootstrap3')

        from models import Test, ColumnProperty
        from views import TestView, ColumnPropertiesView

        admin.add_view(TestView(Test, db.session))
        admin.add_view(ColumnPropertiesView(ColumnProperty, db.session))

    return app
```